Decrypt a txt file back to an image file using AES
I'm trying to decrypt a text file and the information I have so far is that the mode used was CBC and AES as the encryption method and I was also given a secret key vanessa.
This is the original file encrypted_file

I first run this command to decode it to base64
base64 -d encryption_result.txt > decoded_encrypted_data.bin

and then I proceeded to run this command:
openssl aes-256-cbc -md md5 -in decoded_encrypted_data.bin -out decimage


Now I have a file called decimage which I proceeded to do a hexdump on and I noticed it's salted but from then I'm stuck:
$ hexdump -C decimage | head -n 20
00000000  53 61 6c 74 65 64 5f 5f  1e 46 5b 61 2c 83 16 11  |Salted__.F[a,...|
00000010  3d 6e 3f 8e 62 3b 91 f8  38 97 35 c9 3f 8b 93 66  |=n?.b;..8.5.?..f|
00000020  85 c5 26 74 1a c8 47 02  03 51 75 8d 93 db 5a c9  |..&t..G..Qu...Z.|
00000030  8a fa 48 b0 02 cc 1a 88  3a b7 7e 01 ab 69 dc 4c  |..H.....:.~..i.L|
00000040  37 19 fe f3 07 1f 27 57  0c f2 2f b8 56 90 b3 ea  |7.....'W../.V...|
00000050  7f 0c 69 35 2b bb 55 04  e3 6f 1c 7a 7c b7 cb af  |..i5+.U..o.z|...|
00000060  46 4c 94 3f 05 1f ee 22  3a 00 4d 99 fc 1a 1d a6  |FL.?...":.M.....|
00000070  89 34 fd af 78 8e de e6  98 df a0 62 03 f9 7a ab  |.4..x......b..z.|
00000080  7e 09 87 21 c6 0c 3a 0c  d7 f8 fe c6 0c 1a 7d 2a  |~..!..:.......}*|
00000090  55 d7 54 e4 4e 37 92 d5  d9 3a 72 cf 09 6c 2f f0  |U.T.N7...:r..l/.|
000000a0  a3 20 25 d4 94 2f c2 88  6f d8 4d 35 0c 2b c6 f4  |. %../..o.M5.+..|
000000b0  09 38 8f 76 b3 ae 83 85  29 9e 4d ef c7 a4 ab 6b  |.8.v....).M....k|
000000c0  e2 fc d1 e4 f9 7e 25 1f  ca c1 c0 cc 15 3e d3 56  |.....~%......>.V|
000000d0  f7 c5 a4 66 f2 37 c0 5f  0c 16 ec ba 06 78 7c 07  |...f.7._.....x|.|
000000e0  23 22 8c d6 c5 79 bc 51  b0 39 47 de f3 c8 ec 34  |#"...y.Q.9G....4|
000000f0  b0 90 bb d0 09 ff e0 b7  43 3a ce 59 47 47 13 87  |........C:.YGG..|
00000100  7e c1 1f 12 7d 5f f2 22  92 4b ac 07 cb 81 b9 2c  |~...}_.".K.....,|
00000110  d0 26 31 26 fd 06 5c a5  00 09 ba e9 2c d0 53 9d  |.&1&..\.....,.S.|
00000120  33 eb e7 cf 73 b1 da b3  52 0e 70 62 ef 7f 3a ef  |3...s...R.pb..:.|
00000130  00 5c c6 2b 74 21 bb 14  5c 49 cf 8c a7 e8 69 d9  |.\.+t!..\I....i.|



I also tried to derive a key from vanessa but it also doesn't seem to work. How can I aproach this?

man openssl-enc is a useful reference. In particular,

-d Decrypt the input data.

And also, to save you a step,

-a Base64 process the data.This means that if encryption is taking place the data is base64 encoded after encryption. If decryption is set then the input data is base64 decoded before being decrypted.


I tried this and run this command
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -md md5 -in decoded_encrypted_data.bin -out decimage
I got this error:
error reading input file

(a) why aren't you using the decrypt input data flag I've given you? (b) why are you trying to un-base64 a file you've already decoded from base64?

I'm just learning about the RSA and AES encryption method so I get confused sometimes. pardon me for that.
I just run this command
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -in decoded_encrypted_data.bin -d -out decimage
and I get this error bad magic number

You could check the encrypted data file to ensure it's what you expect: file decoded_encrypted_data.bin but from there on I can't help you further as I don't have the original data file

I run 'file decoded_encrypted_data.bin' and I got decoded_encrypted_data.bin: data
let me edit this question so that I can share a link to the file if you don't mind
